# Does java synchronization work with methods of different names?

Tags: java, synchronization

```
class public Test
{
    private int counter;

    public synchronized change()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public change2()
    {
        synchronized(this){
            counter--;
        }
    }

}
```

Can we call change and change2 at the same time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8213220/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/442570/2864740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names have nothing to do with it. What is being *locked* is the object (not the variable, not the reference).

If a thread has started executing a block which synchronizes on an object, any other thread that tries to synchronizes on the same object will block and wait until that original thread completes the execution of its block.

Comment: by object you mean an instance of Test?

Comment: @IceKing In this example, yes. But it can be _any_ instance of _any_ class. (But don't synchronize on instances of `Thread`.)